# How To Provide OR Search for Filters Introduced by User

Tags: django

How To Provide OR Search for Filters Introduced by User

def teachers_list(request):
        qs = Teacher.objects.all()

```
    if request.GET.get('fname'):
        qs = qs.filter(first_name=request.GET.get('fname'))

    if request.GET.get('lname'):
        qs = qs.filter(last_name=request.GET.get('lname'))

    if request.GET.get('email'):
        qs = qs.filter(email=request.GET.get('email'))

    result = '<br>'.join(
        str(teacher)
        for teacher in qs
    )

    # return HttpResponse(result)
    return render(
        request=request,
        template_name='teachers_list.html',
        context={'teachers_list': result}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **Q object**, using it you or operation can be applied in queries

```
  def teachers_list(request):
      qs = Teacher.objects.all()
      search = request.GET.get('search','')
      if search:  
        qs = qs.filter(Q(first_name=search) | Q(last_name=search) | Q(email=search))

      result = '<br>'.join(
        str(teacher)
        for teacher in qs
      )

      # return HttpResponse(result)
      return render(
        request=request,
        template_name='teachers_list.html',
        context={'teachers_list': result}
```

It will be better if you send the searching keyword using  **search** instead of using **3 different keywords**.
You can learn more about Q object from the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Comment: Yes, but in the template you have to pass the parameter fname

def teachers_list(request):
    qs = Teacher.objects.all()
    search = request.GET.get()
    if search:
        qs = qs.filter(Q(first_name=request.GET.get('fname')) | Q(last_name=request.GET.get('lname')) | Q(email=request.GET.get('email')))